# Taking a screenshot of the same area of the screen multiple times

Tags: screen-capture

I often want to take before/after screenshots of things. I often use the inbuilt screenshot tool to screenshot a portion of the screen (cmd + shift + 4). However, having to redrag to get the same portion of the screen (and often get it slightly wrong) is an inconvenience.

Ideally I would like to screenshot a portion of the screen as normal, then trigger a screenshot of the exact same selection as before.

Is this possible?

Comment: New answer added to proposed dupe, as it's been possible natively for a few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mojave, the Screenshot application has allowed the user to define a rectangular of the part of the screen the user wishes to capture. This rectangle can be left unchanged in subsequent screen captures.

[image]

Which is basically what Tetsujin posted as an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211363/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-same-precise-region-with-a-key-combo/455473#455473) similar previous question.